# code for creating context menu does not works properly

Tags: windows, registry, windows-explorer

when i install an application it should add an item to windows explorer context menu using system registry.

but it gives an error that "SOME OR ALL IDENTITY REFERENCES COULD NOT BE RESOLVED"
KINDLY HELP

Comment: You need to provide **a lot more details**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start your application using

```
"Run as Administrator"
```

Then this error wont come up,i think its a problem with Windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it but not fully.......

with the help of creating keys in registry i added an item to windows explorer context menu using c#.the context menu item appears for foleders like mycomp etc but not for files say abc.txt...just as winrar does...

waiting fr reply................